# Armadillo Exception Thrown when using mlpack

Tags: c++, exception, armadillo, mlpack

I'm using the mlpack library which runs on top of the Armadillo linear algebra library. An exception has been thrown referring to the line in the debug.hpp file as shown below:

```
//! if state is true, abort program
template<typename T1>
arma_hot
inline
void
arma_check(const bool state, const T1& x)
  {
  if(state)  { arma_stop_logic_error(arma_str::str_wrapper(x)); }
  }
```

With the message:
`Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFEEC912DE (vcruntime140.dll) in tutorial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000019B35203060.`

Any advice on how to read this error message and what I can do about it? Thanks.

Comment: maybe file a bug report at the [mlpack github repository](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the x64 and x86 re-distributable for visual studio 2015, if you don't have them.

If it still doesn't work it check the compilation settings: either you need static compiling with `/MT` flag or dynamic compile with `/MD` flag.

This flag is under `Project properties/ C/C++ / Code generation`.